Elastic beanstalk and loadbalancer request timeout problem
I have a long-running process in my application, and when I trigger the process by clicking a button on the web interface, it takes an average of 3 - 5 minutes to complete. However, when I perform this process, I receive a 504 bad gateway Time-out error.
In my previous research, I was advised to increase the idle-timeout setting on the load balancer side. I have adjusted this setting to 6 minutes. I'm also sharing a screenshot.

However, when I do this, I can send requests for only 1 minute, and then my server shuts down, sometimes requiring me to restart my Elastic Beanstalk application, or even rebuild it. Can I know the reason for this?

When Elastic Beanstalk is rebuilt, a new load balancer is created. The load balancer security group differs from the one in my Elastic Beanstalk application. When I check the 'Instance traffic and scaling -> EC2 security groups' section in the configuration of my Elastic Beanstalk application, I see two default Group ID values selected.
One of these values is:
sg-0d96c4aa822749360
sg-0c71fd3cdddda9233
However, when I check the 'Security Groups' section on the load balancer side, the Security Group ID value appears as follows:
sg-0d786c6ec4f95ae40
So, it's different from what is in my Elastic Beanstalk application. Later, I looked at the 'Resource-map' section on the load balancer side and noticed that it's not healthy.

ElasticBeanstalk EC2 Security Groups

LoadBalancer Security Groups


What does the long-running process do? Does it open up at a port? Is that part open to the load balancer via a listener? After the long-running process dies, do you still expect to talk to it?

"I have adjusted this setting to 6 minutes" this is an unreliable and error prone way to handle long lived requests.  Queue the request; return a request ID; have the FE poll the BE to determine when the request is complete; then retrieve the results.

"my server shuts down, sometimes requiring me to restart my Elastic Beanstalk application, or even rebuild it. When Elastic Beanstalk is rebuilt, a new load balancer is created".   I'm not sure how you get from "server shuts down" (or what that even means) to "rebuild EB application".

@progfan The name of my lengthy process is generating dynamic PDFs. While creating the PDFs dynamically, I also include images within them. To accomplish this, I make requests to an S3 bucket, and due to the large size of the images, the completion of the PDF operation takes a long time. I didn't fully understand the matter of whether it has a specific port or not. However, when I tried it locally, there were no issues. But on my AWS EC2 instance server, the process gets terminated before completion, leaving the operation unfinished.

@progfan The part about being exposed to a load balancer is that my load balancer is set up on my AWS server and it's working for other processes.

@erik258 When dealing with long-running requests, what should I do? It's blocking my server and making it difficult for me to carry out other tasks. I can't afford to wait for this process to complete for minutes on end. Do you have any solution suggestions?

@erik258 When there's a long-running request on my server that doesn't complete, the server can shut down, requiring me to restart it through Elastic Beanstalk. Otherwise, I keep receiving a 504 Bad Gateway error continuously. Or sometimes, there's no response to my requests at all.

@BerkayKulak, what you're describing in the comments to your question is a webserver anti-pattern. The way to design your app would be to have two different processes either on the same machine or different. The server process that faces user requests should accept the request to create a PDF. The server should handoff the PDF-generation task to a "worker" process/environment. The server should then return a success/failure response of a promise of a successful completion. The client would then use the promise to poll the server periodically for success, in the meantime showing a spinner or a friendly message somewhere. Every time the client polls the server for the result of the promise, the server will check its results queue/database/etc. to respond to the client
